# Скачивание нескольких файлов с сервера

Tags: php

Реализовать скачивание одного файла с сервера на комп пользователя не составляет труда.А если пользователь выбирает из предложенного списка **несколько**файлов, можно ли реализовать на php их скачивание одним потоком? Я имею в виду, сделать так, чтобы окошко "сохранить как " появилось только один раз.

Comment: А если архивом?

Comment: Интересно, как указав одно имя, сохранить много файлов?

Comment: @KoVadim, ну вот - запрашивается одно имя, и по указанному пути сливаются и остальные файлы, имена файлов при этом не меняются. Ладно, будем делать архивом

Comment: Тогда более правильно запрашивать путь. И по нему сохранять файлы. Но вот "из коробки" браузеры этого не умеют.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо. Вот никогда не интересовался, с помощью php можно упаковывать файлы в архив?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.zip.php

Comment: @KoVadim, вот это помощь! Не желаете оформить комментарий в виде ответа?

Comment: Насчёт zip'а варнинг: с большими файлами может не хватить оперативки, т.к. zip, вероятно, весь файл держит в памяти. Для больших файлов предпочтительнее gzip.

Comment: Тут появился более полный ответ, с кодом. Предлагаю вам с ним ознакомиться и принять. (Тот, что сейчас принят, вообще должен бы быть комментарием). http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440640/181472

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать архив на стороне PHP, и все файлы вернуть в одном архиве.

Comment: Код, реализующий эту идею, есть в другом ответе: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/440640/181472

Answer (score 3):

Тут показано как выбрать несколько файлов и скачать одним архивом. http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1763

> Помещаем выбранные файлы в ZIP формат:
>
> ```
> <?php
> $error = "";
> if(isset($_POST['createpdf']))
> {
> $post = $_POST;
> $file_folder = "files/"; // папка с файлами
> if(extension_loaded('zip'))
> {
> if(isset($post['files']) and count($post['files']) > 0)
> {
> // проверяем выбранные файлы
> $zip = new ZipArchive(); // подгружаем библиотеку zip
> $zip_name = time().".zip"; // имя файла
> if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE)
> {
>
> $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
> }
> foreach($post['files'] as $file)
> {
> $zip->addFile($file_folder.$file); // добавляем файлы в zip архив
> }
> $zip->close();
> if(file_exists($zip_name))
> {
> // отдаём файл на скачивание
> header('Content-type: application/zip');
> header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
> readfile($zip_name);
> // удаляем zip файл если он существует
> unlink($zip_name);
> }
>
> }
> else
> $error .= "* Please select file to zip ";
> }
> else
> $error .= "* You dont have ZIP extension";
> }
> ?>
> ```

Автор: Евгений Попов, [под собственной лицензией](http://ruseller.com/page.php?doc=reprint).

Comment: Ответ-ссылка не является ответом, потому что ссылки вскорости становятся невалидными. Предлагаю вам перенести сюда существенные части решения и, оставить ссылку на источник. Тогда это будет хороший ответ.

Comment: я не рекламирую источник, ссылку на которую указал.  если мой ответ вам не нравится, прошу проигнорировать его. если вы являетесь модератором, можете его удалить.

Comment: @abo Проблема не в рекламе. На этом сайте принято, чтобы вопрос и ответы были самодостаточными, то есть включали всю необходимую информацю прямо в тексте поста, а не ссылались на внешний ресурс, который может умереть в любой момент.

Comment: @abo: что вы, я не подозреваю вас в таком. Discord всё верно объяснил.

Comment: @Discord: отредактировал, предлагаю переставить голос.

Comment: @abo: вот я отредактировал, теперь это валидный ответ. ))

Comment: дело в том, что я сам искал ответ на подобный вопрос. кроме данного сайта, я открыл и тот что по ссылке. ну и решил оставить ссылку на него )  спасибо за внесенные корректировки, прошу прощения если что-то не так ляпнул :)

Comment: Всё в порядке, вы правильно поступили, что указали здесь на решение. Поскольку решение адекватное, со временем оно наберет больше голосов (сейчас -3 было как раз за голую ссылку). Кстати, там выше есть в комментарии ссылка на еще одно решение, может быть вам пригодится. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/241099/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0/440640?noredirect=1#comment241123_241099

Comment: Плюс за попытку, но вообще-то код ужасный. Если в течение одной секунды два юзера запросят архив, то скрипт навернётся. Я уж молчу про форматирование и ущербную обработку ошибок.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, браузер (в зависимости от своих настроек) либо не покажет окно с вопросом ни разу, либо покажет на каждый файл.

Но вообще, это не должно бы вызывать особых проблем, поскольку каталог в диалоге уже будет выбран, соответственно, пользователю надо будет только подтвердить скачивания двух оставшихся файлов.